# Is it possible to pattern match on the runtime call enum inside a pallet?

Tags: runtime, extrinsic

I have a pallet that can be used to dispatch other calls to the runtime and it's defined as

```rust
internal_call : Box<<T as Config>::Call>
```

Given that `Call` is just an enum, I want to check if the dispatchable is for a certain pallet, let's say `pallet_kitties::create_kitty` . How can I go about doing that?
If I debug print `internal_call` I get `Call::Kitties(Call::create_kitty)` but this doesn't work in my pallet due to multiple errors :

```rust
match internal_call {
  <T as Config>::Call::Kitties(Call::create_kitty) => {do_something();}
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error    ^^^^ error
  _ => {}
}
```

one of which is `Kitties` is not found for associated type `<T as pallet::Config>::Call`.
I know this is happening probably because the runtime is being built after the fact that all pallets have been built and that the Runtime itself cannot be a dependency for the pallets in order to be able to use `Call::Kitties` as that would cause a dependency cycle.

Is there any easier way to get access to the internal call ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to match the pallet's own calls.

Check the example: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/eae25c901ccd4ef5c3ceb082e3f2c66753879062/frame/election-provider-multi-phase/src/lib.rs#L1197-L1200.

If you want to match other pallets' calls. You could use a trait.

```rs
// in your pallet/lib.rs
trait Config {
  type MatchOtherCalls: CallMatch;
}
trait CallMatch {
  // you could make a more complicative logic here
  fn match(c) -> bool;
}

// in your runtime/lib.rs
struct CallMatcher;
impl CallMatch for CallMatcher {
  fn match(c) -> bool {
    matches!(c, System::remark(..))
  }
}

impl pallet::Config for Runtime {
  type MachOtherCalls = CallMatcher;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain where is `Call<T>` in `type Call = Call<T>;` coming from?

Comment: I should've mentioned it in my question but I need to make calls to other pallets after matching on them to ensure special action when certain dispatchables are called. How would that change `fn match(c)`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps but can fetch pallet id and call id from a call.

```rust
let (pallet_idx, call_idx): (u8, u8) = call
        .using_encoded(|mut bytes| Decode::decode(&mut bytes))
        .expect(
            "decode input is output of Call encode; Call guaranteed to have two enums; qed",
        );
```